# how do I dynamically configure openIdIssuer for 1:1 Azure Static Web App

Tags: next.js, azure-static-web-app

I have an azure static web app that for reasons specific to the industry it is developed for will require me to deploy a single web app per tenant that we are working with. Currently the openIdIssuer is a hardcoded variable that does not allow me to configure it within the environment configuration of the SWA, unlike the clientIdSettingName or the clientSecretSettingName:

```
"auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/v2.0",
          "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
```

Does anyone know of any workarounds or solutions that would allow me to be able to achieve this.

I've attempted to list the variable within the SWA configuration, hoping that it would replace it, however this causes the application authentication to fail.

In searching for potential solutions online, I am unable to find anything that would allow me to dynamically configure the TENANT_ID to ensure that I can achieve my need for deploying this application 1:1.

I've found some solutions that modify the build script to replace the config file, but that isn't what I'm looking for.